# Bug when sorting by votes?

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, votes

I was looking a the questions with the most votes, and I noticed what appears to be a bug in the sorting system.

All the questions on page 1 seem fine, but the votes on questions on page 2 drop off precipitously. The last question on page 2 (30th highest voted question overall) has only six votes.

The first question on page 3 has 27 votes, so it seems back to normal, but then towards the end of page 3, the votes drop again and the last question on page 3 (45th highest voted question overall) has -7 votes.

There seems to be a bug in the sorting system. It does not appear to affect other sites like StackOverflow and AskUbuntu.

[image]

Comment: Gonna ping some people that know more about the engine than I.  Stay tuned.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this and had a higher-level mod tell me she was going to bring it to the devs n such, its possible its fixed by now.

Answer (score 1):

This but isn't affecting me.  The 3rd page has posts with 25-26 votes.  Did you by chance click on the 'per page' buttons to the right of the page buttons in your screenshot?  If you go to page 2, alter the number of posts per page, then click to page 3, you're not going to get the posts that would follow what you had on page 2.

Comment: Nope, I didn't mess with those buttons. But regardless, the issue seems to be fixed now. I cannot reproduce the results today, even though I was able to several times yesterday.